# Multiplying matrices in java

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this code for multiplying two matrices but how do I give it arguments in the main function?

```
public static int [][] multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b){

    int[][] p = new int [a.length][a[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            p[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++)
            p[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "how do I give it arguments in the main function"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to run it. Do i need to give it integers for a and b?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
int[][] b = {{9, 8, 7}, {6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}};

int[][] c = MatrixClass.multiply(a, b); // your multiplied array coming from your MatrixClass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] c = multiply(  new int[][]{
                                 {1, 2, 3},
                                 {4, 5, 6},
                                 {7, 8, 9}
                       },
                       new int[][]{
                                 {9, 8, 7},
                                 {6, 5, 4},
                                 {3, 2, 1}
                       });
```